# Why is permisson denied(forked repo)? The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, github

I created new PAT today. Repo is public

```
git push
Username for 'https://github.com': MilenkoMarkovic
Password for 'https://MilenkoMarkovic@github.com': 
remote: Permission to MilenkoMarkovic/github-action-maven-example-start.git denied to MilenkoMarkovic.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/MilenkoMarkovic/github-action-maven-example-start/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Fine-grained
[image]

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the introduction of [fine-grained personal access tokens](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-18-introducing-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens/), make sure you have created a PAT which is not limited to one repository.

Do create a [classic PAT](https://github.blog/2022-10-18-introducing-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens-for-github/#fine-grained-personal-access-tokens-in-action), with a [repo scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes), and that PAT should allow you to push to your repository.